# PDO shown as "Not Installed" in Froxlor

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ubuntu-14.04, php-ini

I am trying to install froxlor on Ubuntu 14.04 and have already installed the PHP5 MYSQL PDO Extension.

When running code:

```
php -i|grep PDO
```

It results in

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
```

But froxlor shows the PDO Extension as "Not Installed".
Curl is also installed and is shown as "Not Installed".

If it helps any here is a piccture of the install result page: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6cVY3leu3GIWFoxLXJjWTB2QzNHeGtRMUNRQ3hDMGxYcS0w/view?usp=sharing)

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three different php.ini files when using php on Ubuntu.

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

They can differ and depending on how php is invoked one or the other .ini file is used.
phpinfo() / php -i can tell you which one was used.